# How do I use the result of the outer observer in the inner observer of switchMapTo?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am using `switchMapTo` to create an inner stream that is triggered by an outer observer.

### What I'd like to do (but can't)

```
// a change in value of categoryId triggers the inner observer to reinitialize
this.category$ = this.categoryId$.pipe(
  switchMapTo((newCategoryId) => 
    // inner stream is reinitialized using result from outer stream
    this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity(newCategoryId)
  )
)
```

#### ...because this is how switchMapTo actually works

`.switchMapTo` doesn't actually return the result from the outer observer to the inner observer. As far as I can tell, the inner stream is initialized just once and then it is triggered by each new emission from the outer observer

How `.switchMapTo` actually works:

```
this.category$ = this.categoryId$.pipe(
  switchMapTo(
    this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity(newCategoryId) // <= where does newCategoryId come from now?
  )
)
```

#### And the inner observer is only initialized once

Unfortunately this doesn't work either:

```
this.category$ = this.categoryId$.pipe(
  tap((newValue) => {
     this.currentCategoryId = newValue
  }),
  switchMapTo(() =>{
    this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity(this.currentCategoryId)
  }
  )
)
```

Because the inner observer is only initialized once (not at every emission from the outer observer) and so the value of `this.currentCategoryId` is hard-coded in the first time it's evaluated.

#### Is it possible to do what I want to do?

I'm pretty stuck. I'd like to have the effect of `switchMapTo` i.e. the outer observer triggers the emission of a new inner stream. But it needs to be a *new* inner stream and not just the repetition of the original one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `switchMap`, not `switchMapTo`...

```
this.category$ = this.categoryId$.pipe(
  switchMap((newCategoryId) => 
    // inner stream is reinitialized using result from outer stream
    this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity(newCategoryId)
  )
)
```

`switchMapTo` is essentially a shorthand  for a `switchMap` that switches into a static observable that doesn't care about the outer observable, not a dynamic one that relies on it, that's what `switchMap` is for.

Similar logic applies to all operators with a `To` variant such as `map` and `mapTo` ... you usually want the plain one, the `To` variants are more special case.

Comment: I've already tried switchmap but it doesn't unfortunately do the job. `switchMap` works when you need the outer observer to trigger the inner observer. However it doesn't work when the inner observer subsequently emits a stream. In that case switchMap will only return the first emission from the inner stream. I need it to emit all of the emissions from the inner stream.

Comment: you're mistaken on `switchMap` docs: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap  `switchMap` stays subscribed to the inner observable till it completes or the outter emits again, at which point it resubscribes to the inner. Either way, `switchMapTo` is literally just a convenience wrapper around `switchMap` ... they're functionality is identical besides the static vs dynamic part

Comment: I would have loved it if your example worked but I have found out through bitter trial and error that in the setup you have, the inner observer can never trigger `this.category$` to emit a new value *unless* the outer observer also emits a value. The inner observer is dependent on the outer one to be evaluated. I want it to evaluate independently

Comment: what you're saying doesn't make sense. the inner observable doesn't and shouldn't ever trigger the outer observable. maybe you should put more code and a plain english description of what you're trying to accomplish as you seem confused on some rxjs concepts. I'm certain I can help you through whatever the issue is if I know more.

Comment: you can see here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/switchMapTo.ts ... `switchMapTo` is actually just implemented as a wrapper around `switchMap` ... they're the same.

Comment: amazing - I'll come back with a clearer description of the problem (after dinner). I have lost literally 6 hours trying to make this work and I am super grateful for any help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221310/discussion-between-peter-nixey-and-bryan60).

Comment: Just to follow up on this -your proposed solution was exctly right. One of (many) reasaons I'd been seeing problems when I first experimetned because for some reason, `.categoriesQuery` was ceasing to work correctly and so the observer structure was correct but the inner observer simply wasn't emitting.